# Angular design question - Dynamically loading Angular component and managing state independently

Tags: angular, state

We have an angular application for the business transaction (one NgModule) and also our own state management using Behavior Subject service which helps notify all the components of that app when state changes.

The next requirement is to allow user add multiple of those transactions meaning that we need to load that component dynamically (which should be straight-forward to do) and most importantly the state of each should not affect each other since they all are independent. The services in angular are singleton, when something changes on one component (i.e. one transaction) other transaction components are being notified. Is there any pattern for this type of functionality where the same component needs to be loaded multiple times and independently without affecting each other.

Answer (score 0):

First off you can lazy load the module being used therefore any component on that route and its children will behave with service in your singleton pattern and keep state management. An angular architecture technique is to use a "wrapper component" that makes use of all of your module components as such  . This will give you the modular architecture you need for the dynamic and transactional requirement.

Here is an example of a wrapper component:

**HTML:**

```
<main [@childRouteFadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </main>
```

**TS:**

```
if (window.history.state) {
      if (window.history.state.app == null) {
        const enrollId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('someParam');
        console.log('check router state');
        this.apiClient.reloadEnrollment(someId).subscribe((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          this.formService.enrollmentForm.patchValue(resp);
          this.loading = false;
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to make sure, I need state of these dynamically loaded components to NOT interfere with each other. Currently I use *ngFor to load the same angular component multiple times and because they use State Facade services, they all get notified what the state changes which I would like to avoid.

Comment: OK, so in your case you should make one component as a wrapper component that works with your service. Your child components should have something like this @Input()
    todo:Todo;

    @Output()
    toggle = new EventEmitter<Object>(); this way each of your components are transactional with the behavior subject only related to each child component. You could also use ViewEncapsulation / shadow DOM